# $a,b,N$ are integers. Prove $x=x_0+\cdots$, $\ \ y=y_0+\cdots $ are solutions to $ax+by=N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

I'm asked to prove that if $a,b,N$ are integers, then in the equation:

$$ax+by=N$$

I must prove that the integers $$x=x_0+\frac{b}{d}t,\ y=y_0-\frac{a}{d}t$$
are solutions to the equation.

where $d=gcd(a,b)$

This is easy to prove, since if we substitute $x,y$ in the equation we get:

$$a(x_0+\frac{b}{d}t)+b(y_0-\frac{a}{d}t)=N\implies ax_0 + by_0=N$$

So $x_0$ and $y_0$ are solutions.

Then I'm asked to prove the converse: let $x$ and $y$ be integer solutions to the equation. Then, they have the form

$$x=x_0+\frac{b}{d}t,\ y=y_0-\frac{a}{d}t$$.

First of all, I don't know how to start. Also, I don't know what this exercise is trying to make me see. Maybe a useful theorem?
Does someone know how to start with the equation

$$ax+by=N$$

where $a,b,N$ are integers, and then intuitively find that the solutions are in the form presented by the exercise?
I think it has something to do with Bezout's identity, it kinda looks like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be a particular solution, and let $(x,y)$ be any solution. Then $ax_0+by_0=ax+by=N$. Subtracting, we find that $a(x-x_0)=-b(y-y_0)$.

Let $a=da'$ and $b=db'$. Then $a'$ and $b'$ are relatively prime, and
$$a'(x-x_0)=-b'(y-y_0).$$
Note that $b'$ divides $a'(x-x_0)$. Since $a'$ and $b'$ are relatively prime, we conclude that $b'$ divides $x-x_0$. So there is an integer $t$ such that $x-x_0=b't$. Substituting, we find that $y-y_0=-a't$.

The result is quite useful. It says that if we know a particular solution of the linear Diophantine equation $ax+by=N$, then we have a "formula" that describes all solutions.  More geometrically, once we have found a point with integer coordinates on the line $ax+by=N$, we can obtain a simple parametric description of all such points.

Comment: could you please be more clear in the part $a'$ and $b'$ are relatively prime?

Comment: If $a'$ and $b'$ are not relatively prime, then there is an $e\gt 1$ such that $e$ divides $a'$ and $b'$. But then $de$ divides both $a$ and $b$. Since $e\gt 1$, we have $de\gt d$, contradicting the fact that $d$ is the **greatest**  common divisor of $a$ and $b$.